# How to "cache" time-consuming results?

Tags: python, caching

I often have the case where I have data which is time consuming to fetch. This becomes particularly annoying when debugging.

What I usually do is that I first run the query and dump the result into a pickle:

```
import pickle
d = the_data_query_which_takes_time()
with open("cache.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(d, f)
```

and then, for debugging / testing:

```
import pickle
#d = the_data_query_which_takes_time()
with open("cache.pickle", "rb") as f:
    d = pickle.load(f)
```

While this essentially works, it is not a very practical way of caching the results. Is there a more pythonic and reusable way?

Comment: How often do you revisit/use the data from `the_data_query_which_takes_time()`?  Are your *debugging/testing* sessions separated from `the_data_query_which_takes_time()` by considerable lengths of time?  Do you power your computer down between query and use?  Do you need the data *serialized* and stored  so it can be accessed later or from different machines?

Comment: Typically the time-consuming data is queried via an API as part of the script. It is then processed further. My question is about comfort/speed during the debugging sessions. I do not need this data when the script runs in prod. It is to ensure that when I start the script 20 times in debug mode I do not have to wait 20 times for the data to be fetched. My example is really typical of what I do right now: that is, load the pre-fetched data in the same format as if it was actually downloaded to cut time.

Comment: How would you like the process to be different from the way you are doing it now? What do you mean by `it is not a very practical way`?   Does the memoization technique @jrd1 posted look like what you want?

Comment: @wwii: the memoization technique with decorators is what I will go for, trying to adapt it to my case. I was indeed looking for a way to "modify the function without modifying it" -- and it looks like decorators are the way to go. Modifying the structure of the program (by commenting out some pieces, uncommenting some, etc.) is the "not very practical way" I was mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something called `memoization`:

> The term "memoization" was introduced by Donald Michie in the year
>   1968. It's based on the Latin word memorandum, meaning "to be remembered". It's not a misspelling of the word memorization, though
>   in a way it has something in common. Memoisation is a technique used
>   in computing to speed up programs. This is accomplished by memorizing
>   the calculation results of processed input such as the results of
>   function calls. If the same input or a function call with the same
>   parameters is used, the previously stored results can be used again
>   and unnecessary calculation are avoided. In many cases a simple array
>   is used for storing the results, but lots of other structures can be
>   used as well, such as associative arrays, called hashes in Perl or
>   dictionaries in Python.
>
> Memoization can be explicitly programmed by the programmer, but some
>   programming languages like Python provide mechanisms to automatically
>   memoize functions.

From a Pythonic perspective, this is usually done via decorators or via classes. Here's a simple case involving decorators:

```
def memoize(func):
    S = {}
    def wrappingfunction(*args):
        if args not in S:
            S[args] = func(*args)
        return S[args]
    return wrappingfunction

# This function is now memoized
@memoize
def cube(x):
    return x**3
```

Here are a few useful links to help you get started:

http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary

http://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/a-primer-on-python-decorators/

http://www.pycogsci.info/?p=221